# @EnableWebSecurity debug boolean flag handled by profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The annotation `@EnableWebSecurity` includes an attribute to enable or disable the debug mode. This attribute is a boolean field.

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

I would like to en- or disable the flag by the spring-profile I use. Actually I can not use `SpEL` because its a `String`. Is there any easy workaround the enable/disable the flag by profiles?

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true -> *should be handled by profile*)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was easy. `WebSecurity` itself has the debug mode as attribute. So if you override the `WebSecurity` you can setup debugmode:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${isDebugMode}")
    private boolean isDebugMode;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(isDebugMode);
    }
}
```